# android typeface fill transparent areas in ttf

Tags: android, truetype, android-typeface

I'm using a ttf for my fonts in my app. The font i'm using is like:
http://www.dafont.com/unlearned-bitmap.font?nb_ppp=50

When i print text on a textview, the area in and around the strokes of the font is transparent, so i see only the black strokes of the font. When i set the backgroundcolor of the textview, the area inside the black strokes is colored, but also the area outside the strokes. Is there a way to color the inside of the font, but not the area around the strokes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use setTextColor()

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "CustomFont.ttf");
setTypeface(tf);
yourTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "AnyFont.ttf");
setTypeface(tf);
textview.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
```